# Вывести на экран xml с отступами

Tags: python, xml, lxml, python-3.x

помогите пожалуйста красиво, с отступами вывести(на экран) xml из строки

```
import lxml.etree
import lxml.html

xml = '<catalog><category>iPhone</category><category>iPad</category><category>iPod</category><category>iMac</category><category>MacBook</category><category>Mac Mini</category><category>Чехлы</category><category>Защитные   пленки</category><category>Акксессуары</category><category>Наушники и гарнитуры</category><category>Переходники и Провода</category><category>Автомобильные аксессуары</category><category>Aккустические системы</category><category>Зарядные устройства</category><category>Видео очки</category><category>Wi-Fi оборудование</category><category>Аккумуляторы и блоки питания</category><category>BlackBerry</category><category>Подставки и док-станции</category><category>Игрушки</category><category>Цифровые ручки</category><category>Полезные устройства</category><category>Планшетные компьютеры</category><category>Samsung</category><category>GoPro</category><category>Память</category></catalog>'
rt = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml)
print(lxml.etree.tostring(rt, pretty_print=True))
```

у меня xml выводится в таком виде:

```
b'<catalog>\n  <category>iPhone</category>\n  <category>iPad</category>\n  <category>iPod</category>\n  <category>iMac</category>\n  <category>MacBook</category>\n  <category>Mac Mini</category>\n  <category>&#1063;&#1077;&#1093;&#1083;&#1099;</category>\n  <category>&#1047;&#1072;&#1097;&#1080;&#1090;&#1085;&#1099;&#1077;   &#1087;&#1083;&#1077;&#1085;&#1082;&#1080;</category>\n  <category>&#1040;&#1082;&#1082;&#1089;&#1077;&#1089;&#1089;&#1091;&#1072;&#1088;&#1099;</category>\n  <category>&#1053;&#1072;&#1091;&#1096;&#1085;&#1080;&#1082;&#1080; &#1080; &#1075;&#1072;&#1088;&#1085;&#1080;&#1090;&#1091;&#1088;&#1099;</category>\n  <category>&#1055;&#1077;&#1088;&#1077;&#1093;&#1086;&#1076;&#1085;&#1080;&#1082;&#1080; &#1080; &#1055;&#1088;&#1086;&#1074;&#1086;&#1076;&#1072;</category>\n  <category>&#1040;&#1074;&#1090;&#1086;&#1084;&#1086;&#1073;&#1080;&#1083;&#1100;&#1085;&#1099;&#1077; &#1072;&#1082;&#1089;&#1077;&#1089;&#1089;&#1091;&#1072;&#1088;&#1099;</category>\n  <category>A&#1082;&#1082;&#1091;&#1089;&#1090;&#1080;&#1095;&#1077;&#1089;&#1082;&#1080;&#1077; &#1089;&#1080;&#1089;&#1090;&#1077;&#1084;&#1099;</category>\n  <category>&#1047;&#1072;&#1088;&#1103;&#1076;&#1085;&#1099;&#1077; &#1091;&#1089;&#1090;&#1088;&#1086;&#1081;&#1089;&#1090;&#1074;&#1072;</category>\n  <category>&#1042;&#1080;&#1076;&#1077;&#1086; &#1086;&#1095;&#1082;&#1080;</category>\n  <category>Wi-Fi &#1086;&#1073;&#1086;&#1088;&#1091;&#1076;&#1086;&#1074;&#1072;&#1085;&#1080;&#1077;</category>\n  <category>&#1040;&#1082;&#1082;&#1091;&#1084;&#1091;&#1083;&#1103;&#1090;&#1086;&#1088;&#1099; &#1080; &#1073;&#1083;&#1086;&#1082;&#1080; &#1087;&#1080;&#1090;&#1072;&#1085;&#1080;&#1103;</category>\n  <category>BlackBerry</category>\n  <category>&#1055;&#1086;&#1076;&#1089;&#1090;&#1072;&#1074;&#1082;&#1080; &#1080; &#1076;&#1086;&#1082;-&#1089;&#1090;&#1072;&#1085;&#1094;&#1080;&#1080;</category>\n  <category>&#1048;&#1075;&#1088;&#1091;&#1096;&#1082;&#1080;</category>\n  <category>&#1062;&#1080;&#1092;&#1088;&#1086;&#1074;&#1099;&#1077; &#1088;&#1091;&#1095;&#1082;&#1080;</category>\n  <category>&#1055;&#1086;&#1083;&#1077;&#1079;&#1085;&#1099;&#1077; &#1091;&#1089;&#1090;&#1088;&#1086;&#1081;&#1089;&#1090;&#1074;&#1072;</category>\n  <category>&#1055;&#1083;&#1072;&#1085;&#1096;&#1077;&#1090;&#1085;&#1099;&#1077; &#1082;&#1086;&#1084;&#1087;&#1100;&#1102;&#1090;&#1077;&#1088;&#1099;</category>\n  <category>Samsung</category>\n  <category>GoPro</category>\n  <category>&#1055;&#1072;&#1084;&#1103;&#1090;&#1100;</category>\n</catalog>\n'
```

но это не то, что нужно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ваш код и так выводит на екран все красиво и с отступами. Как вы добились такого вывода я не знаю.

Если вы хотите чтобы русские символы не заменялись на эквиваленты, используйте:

```
print(lxml.etree.tostring(rt, pretty_print=True, encoding='utf-8'))
```

Comment: это я тоже пробовал. результат ещё хуже: 83\xd1\x80\xd1\x8b</category>\n  <category>\xd0\x9f\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd1\x85\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8 \xd0\xb8 \xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb0</category>\n  <category>\xd0\x90\xd0\xb2\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xb0\xd0\xba\xd1\

Comment: Где вы исполняете этот код?
Прямо в интерпретаторе?

перед  строкой с xml поставте u

    xml = u'<catalog><category>iPhone...

Comment: нет, исполняю в файле .py . пробовал поставить u. не помогло...

Comment: Понял в чем дело. Это новшества python3.
Используйте:

    print(lxml.etree.tounicode(rt, pretty_print=True))

Comment: так заработало. спасибо)